# Is this proof in Fitch possible?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Good evening! I have got a question about this following practice proof my professor has given me:

Premise:

1. ∃x ((P(a) ∧ ∀y (P(y) → y = x)) ∧ R(x))
2. P(b) ∧ ∀y (P(y) → y = b)

Prove:
R(b)

I understand that this proof is *true*, however, I cannot seem to prove it using Fitch rules.

This is what I have so far. How should I go about proving this further? The way I was thinking was this: if I can somehow get to P(a) ∧ ∀y (P(y) → y = b)) ∧ R(b)), I can get R(b) through conjunction elimination. However, I am not sure how the second premise can even help with that.

Edit: It seems as if this proof can be done with only elimination rules. Still need to figure it out.

[image]

Comment: First, give us an informal proof. Then, we can help you translate it into a formal proof.

Comment: @MarkSaving the way I was thinking was this: if I can get to P(a) ∧ ∀y (P(y) → y = b)) ∧ R(b)), I can get R(b) through conjunction elimination. However, I am not sure how the second premise can help with that.

Comment: It's better for you to add above thoughts to your original post, also your attached Fitch UI is illegible...

Comment: @mohottnad added my thoughts to the original post, the UI seems to be fine on my side, what is illegible about it?

Comment: It appears too small to read on my desktop.

Comment: @mohottnad I have posted a bigger picture, it should be better.

Comment: Without 2nd premise you cannot be sure there must exist $b$ in the domain, and its second conjunct assures you as long as P(y) holds y must be $b$...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132345/discussion-between-norwegianwood-and-mohottnad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is you cannot substitute $b$ initially, only an arbitrary constant $c$ is allowed. Then you can try use your 2nd premise's 2nd conjunct to prove $c=b$ within the same subproof. Then you also have to invoke your related equality rules
and $P(b)$ is needed here to let you invoke ∀-elim rule (let you safely substitute $b$ for $y$) in the subsequent subproof to arrive at $c=b$...